# How can I run a Terminal command as "root"?

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal, apt

I tried to install Git using this command `apt-get install git`, but getting this:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

What's problem?

I tried these :

*sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get -f install*,

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `sudo  apt-get install git` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main key word/phrase to find solution is **are you root ?**

That means the command needs root privileges to run.

From `man` page of `sudo`

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified
>        by the security policy.

Use `sudo` to run a command with root privileges.

So run `sudo apt-get install git`

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

then just type your password (invisible). I also installed git with elementary, the same as Ubuntu and works.

Also, you can use the root command **su** (not recomended) instead of **sudo** but you need to create a password for use su with **sudo passwd root**

Answer (score 1):

For `apt-get install git` you can get this result, but for other commands it cannot be. you need to use `sudo` to run commands as a root user from another user. you can turn into root user in terminal `sudo su` command.

for your issue check whether you are running update manager or synaptic package manager.

you also can check the processes running as root using this command.

```
ps -u root
```

then kill the program using this.

```
sudo killall <appname> # Example: sudo killall synaptic
```

Answer (score -2):

Run sudo su it will look like this:

```
root@_______-Computer:~$
```

Comment: sudo su is actually double. sudo apt-get install git should work.